# Spring Boot 1.5.4 Filter out null values in json response

Tags: spring-boot, null

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.4 version . I am using `spring-ws getWebServiceTemplate()` to make a webservice call. The SOAP response has lot of null values for the fields.

I am trying to filter out the null values in the JSON response. None of the following approaches seem to work:

1. Setting the property in the `application.properties`:

```js
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion:NON_NULL`
```

2. Setting it in Configuration class using `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`:

```js
@Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();        
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        return builder;
    }
```

Please advise.

lva

Answer (score 2):

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE version, and you can reference
[customize-the-jackson-objectmapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Following code is work:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        @Bean
        public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
            builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            return builder;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DbeeApiApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Or you can filter from `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, for example:

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for(HttpMessageConverter<?> converter: converters) {
            if(converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)converter).getObjectMapper();
                mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer as to how it will solve the issue. That will also help avoid same issues in future. Code-only answers are not highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following in application.properties worked.

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
```

Comment: nice and clean solution